# How to delete the "_files" folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems

Sometimes when saving a file, for example when you save an HTML page from your browser on your hard drive, you get a folder with the suffix `_files` additionally to the file itself.

[image: example]

However, when you delete either one of these items, the other one gets deleted, too. Sometimes I only want to keep the file, but not the folder. Then I would have to open it in a text editor, save it under a different location and then delete those two items.

**Is there a canonical way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rename one of those. It will prompt you with a message, just confirm it.
Then you can delete either. I prefer renaming the html file because then you have chance to go back to previous state.

Comment: Touché. Didn't know this was so easy. Well, Windows users learn every day :D

Comment: Background: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887(VS.85).aspx#connected